# How can I set the color of a bar (matplotlib) according to a value in a dataframe (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a barplot from a dataframe. But I want to color each bar according to a value from the column 'red' in the dataframe.
I have the following code:

```
plt.bar(df.index, df['Mean'], yerr = df['yerr'], capsize=7, color = (df['red'], 0, 0, 0.6))
```

I would like to take the value from the column 'red' (which goes from 0 to 1) but it keeps failing. How would you do it?

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work. You have to create blue, green, and alpha columns of common length, then zip them all together with red.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [1, 1, 0.1],
    [2, 1, 0.2],
    [3, 1, 0.3],
    [4, 1, 0.4],
    [5, 1, 0.5],
    [6, 1, 0.6],
    [7, 1, 0.7],
    [8, 1, 0.8],
    [9, 1, 0.9],
]
columns = ['Mean', 'yerr', 'red']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

r = df['red']
g = np.zeros(r.shape[0])
b = np.zeros(r.shape[0])
a = np.ones(r.shape[0]) * 0.6
plt.bar(df.index, df['Mean'], yerr=df['yerr'], capsize=7,
        color=list(zip(r, g, b, a)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Can you explain why it is done that way?

Comment: @CarlosOlivares If you look at the [`color` option in the doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), you can see it expects a scaler (so all the bars would be the same color), or an array-like object. And "array-like" really means a 2-D array where each row is a separate (r, g, b, a) parameter and each column corresponds to a data point. It's not totally obvious, I agree. Most of what I know about matplotlib was learned through trial and error. You're welcome, and best of luck to you!

Comment: Whoops! I meant to say that each row is (r, g, b, a) and there should be as many _rows_ as there are data points.